# Finding a limit of a function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let 
 $$u(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sin(nx_1)\sinh(nx_2)$$

with $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. What happens to $u$ as $n \to +\infty.$ ?

This is what I tried to do :
$$-\frac{1}{n^2}\sinh(nx_2)\le u(x_1,x_2)\le\frac{1}{n^2}\sinh(nx_2)$$ 
but I don't know how to conclude.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @mostafa, welcome to MSE. Can you add your attempts and efforts in the question (not the comments). Questions that don't show any efforts are sometimes poorly received on MSE.

Answer (score 0):

For $x_2=0 \, \lor \, x_1=k\pi$

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sin(nx_1)\sinh(nx_2)=0$$

otherwise observe that

$$\sinh(nx_2) \sim \frac12e^{n|x_2|}\quad\lor\quad \sinh(nx_2) \sim -\frac12e^{n|x_2|}$$

but for $x_1\neq k\pi$ we have that $\sin (nx_1)$ doesn't converge.

Refer to the related

- [Find all $x$ such that lim $\sin (nx)$ exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857512/505767)

Comment: I don't see how you prove that in the second case we don't have a limit ? can you please explain more?  Thanks

Comment: @mostafa Recall that $\sinh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ then depending upon the sing of $x_2$ we have that $\sinh(nx_2)/n^2 \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: $\{\sin nx_1\mid n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ is not dense in $[-1,1]$, if $x_1$ happens to be a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've indeed considered $x_1 \neq k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Check what happens with, say $x_1=\pi/5$. Only  finitely many values of $\sin nx_1$ in that case. Doesn't look like a dense set. Doesn't really disturb the conclusion, just the justification.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, can you please explain when we don't have a limit and how to prove that please ? Thanks

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks I get your point. I try to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

In general the limit does not exist. For example, if $x_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $x_2=1$, the result is $n^{-2}\sinh n$ times either $0$ or $\pm 1$ depending on $n(\operatorname{mod} 4)$. This result is a vanishing subsequence, but also subsequences diverging to $\pm\infty$. On the other hand, the limit can exist, e.g. if some $x_i=0$.